# Rails has_many :through using same table twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

I am having issues getting my Model relationships set up correctly.  I have the following classes:

**personal_portfolio.rb**

```
class PersonalPortfolio < Portfolio

  has_many :user_stake_in_portfolios, :foreign_key => :possession_id

  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :managers, :through => :user_stake_in_portfolios, :source => :user

  has_many :company_permissions, :foreign_key => :owner_id
  has_many :company_permissions_as_viewer, :class_name => 'CompanyPermission', :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => 'can_view_info = true || can_edit_cap_table = true || can_view_key_metric = true || can_view_all_metrics = true || can_view_cap_table = true || can_edit_managers = true || can_edit_info = true || can_edit_metrics = true'
  has_many :companies_as_viewer, :class_name => 'Company', :through => :company_permissions_as_viewer, :source => :entity

  has_many :company_permissions_as_manager, :class_name => 'CompanyPermission', :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => { :can_edit_managers => true }
  has_many :companies_as_manager, :class_name => 'Company', :through => :company_permissions_as_manager, :source => :entity

  has_many :portfolio_permissions, :foreign_key => :owner_id
  has_many :portfolio_permissions_as_viewer, :class_name => 'PortfolioPermission', :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => 'can_view_info = true || can_edit_cap_table = true || can_view_key_metric = true || can_view_all_metrics = true || can_view_cap_table = true || can_edit_managers = true || can_edit_info = true || can_edit_metrics = true'
  has_many :portfolios_as_viewer, :class_name => 'Portfolio', :through => :portfolio_permissions_as_viewer, :source => :entity

  has_many :portfolio_permissions_as_manager, :class_name => 'PortfolioPermission', :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => { :can_edit_managers => true }
  has_many :portfolios_as_manager, :class_name => 'GroupPortfolio', :through => :portfolio_permissions_as_manager, :source => :entity

  after_create :add_manager
  ...
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :user_stake_in_portfolios, foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_many :portfolios, through: :user_stake_in_portfolios
  has_many :personal_portfolios, through: :user_stake_in_portfolios, :class_name => 'PersonalPortfolio', :source => :portfolio, :conditions => { :type => 'PersonalPortfolio' }
  has_many :companies, through: :portfolios, source: :portfolio_companies, class_name: 'Company'

  has_many :managed_portfolios, :through => :personal_portfolios, :source => :portfolios_as_manager
  has_many :viewable_portfolios, :through => :personal_portfolios, :source => :portfolios_as_viewer

  has_many :managed_companies, :through => :personal_portfolios, :source => :companies_as_manager
  has_many :viewable_companies, :through => :personal_portfolios, :source => :companies_as_viewer
  ...
end
```

What is strange is that if I run the command `User.find(3).personal_portfolios.first.portfolios_as_viewer` I get the results I expect (3 portfolios).  But the issue is when I then try `User.find(3).viewable_portfolios`, I only get 1 portfolio (which is 1 of the three).  User.`viewable_portfolios` is a `has_many :through` using `PersonalPortfolio.portfolios_as_viewer` as the source.

When looking at the query produced by the second command, you can see that it is using the `portfolios` table twice:

```
SELECT `portfolios`.*
FROM   `portfolios`
       INNER JOIN `permissions`
               ON `portfolios`.`id` = `permissions`.`entity_id`
       INNER JOIN `portfolios` `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`
               ON `permissions`.`owner_id` =
                  `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`.`id`
       INNER JOIN `stakes`
               ON `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`.`id` =
                  `stakes`.`possession_id`
WHERE  `permissions`.`type` IN ( 'PortfolioPermission' )
   AND `portfolios`.`type` IN ( 'PersonalPortfolio' )
   AND `stakes`.`type` IN ( 'UserStakeInPortfolio' )
   AND `stakes`.`owner_id` = 3
   AND ( can_view_info = true
          || can_edit_cap_table = true
          || can_view_key_metric = true
          || can_view_all_metrics = true
          || can_view_cap_table = true
          || can_edit_managers = true
          || can_edit_info = true
          || can_edit_metrics = true )
   AND ( `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`.`type` = 'PersonalPortfolio' )
```

It's strange to me because `User.find(3).managed_portfolios == User.find(3).personal_portfolios.first.portfolios_as_manager` returns true while `User.find(3).viewable_portfolios == User.find(3).personal_portfolios.first.portfolios_as_viewer` returns false.  And companies work just fine (though not indicative of the right relationships as the dependencies/data vary) though the relationships look to be the same.

**The Question**
How can I get `User.find(3).viewable_portfolios` return the same as `User.find(3).personal_portfolios.first.portfolios_as_viewer`?

**Helpful Outputs**

```
1.9.3-p362 :122 > User.find(3).viewable_portfolios
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Portfolio Load (1.1ms)  SELECT `portfolios`.* FROM `portfolios` INNER JOIN `permissions` ON `portfolios`.`id` = `permissions`.`entity_id` INNER JOIN `portfolios` `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join` ON `permissions`.`owner_id` = `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`.`id` INNER JOIN `stakes` ON `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`.`id` = `stakes`.`possession_id` WHERE `permissions`.`type` IN ('PortfolioPermission') AND `portfolios`.`type` IN ('PersonalPortfolio') AND `stakes`.`type` IN ('UserStakeInPortfolio') AND `stakes`.`owner_id` = 3 AND (can_view_info = true || can_edit_cap_table = true || can_view_key_metric = true || can_view_all_metrics = true || can_view_cap_table = true || can_edit_managers = true || can_edit_info = true || can_edit_metrics = true) AND (`personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`.`type` = 'PersonalPortfolio')
 => [#<PersonalPortfolio id: 3, name: "Manager Man's portfolio", established: "2013-09-24", created_at: "2013-09-24 23:20:34", updated_at: "2013-09-24 23:20:34", type: "PersonalPortfolio", base_capital_invested: nil, total_shares: nil, logo_file_name: nil, logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil, city: nil, state: nil, invited_manager_email: nil, claim_code: nil, angellist_url: nil, facebook_url: nil, linkedin_url: nil, twitter_url: nil, website_url: nil, longitude: nil, latitude: nil, is_single_use_fund: false, tagline: nil, thumb_file_name: nil, thumb_content_type: nil, thumb_file_size: nil, thumb_updated_at: nil, use_committed_capital: true, owner_id: 3>] 

1.9.3-p362 :123 > User.find(3).viewable_portfolios.count
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
   (2.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `portfolios` INNER JOIN `permissions` ON `portfolios`.`id` = `permissions`.`entity_id` INNER JOIN `portfolios` `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join` ON `permissions`.`owner_id` = `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`.`id` INNER JOIN `stakes` ON `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`.`id` = `stakes`.`possession_id` WHERE `permissions`.`type` IN ('PortfolioPermission') AND `portfolios`.`type` IN ('PersonalPortfolio') AND `stakes`.`type` IN ('UserStakeInPortfolio') AND `stakes`.`owner_id` = 3 AND (can_view_info = true || can_edit_cap_table = true || can_view_key_metric = true || can_view_all_metrics = true || can_view_cap_table = true || can_edit_managers = true || can_edit_info = true || can_edit_metrics = true) AND (`personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`.`type` = 'PersonalPortfolio')
 => 1 

1.9.3-p362 :124 > User.find(3).personal_portfolios.first.portfolios_as_viewer
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  PersonalPortfolio Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `portfolios`.* FROM `portfolios` INNER JOIN `stakes` ON `portfolios`.`id` = `stakes`.`possession_id` WHERE `stakes`.`type` IN ('UserStakeInPortfolio') AND `portfolios`.`type` IN ('PersonalPortfolio') AND `stakes`.`owner_id` = 3 AND (`portfolios`.`type` = 'PersonalPortfolio') LIMIT 1
  Portfolio Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `portfolios`.* FROM `portfolios` INNER JOIN `permissions` ON `portfolios`.`id` = `permissions`.`entity_id` WHERE `permissions`.`type` IN ('PortfolioPermission') AND `permissions`.`owner_id` = 3 AND (can_view_info = true || can_edit_cap_table = true || can_view_key_metric = true || can_view_all_metrics = true || can_view_cap_table = true || can_edit_managers = true || can_edit_info = true || can_edit_metrics = true)
 => [#<PersonalPortfolio id: 3, name: "Manager Man's portfolio", established: "2013-09-24", created_at: "2013-09-24 23:20:34", updated_at: "2013-09-24 23:20:34", type: "PersonalPortfolio", base_capital_invested: nil, total_shares: nil, logo_file_name: nil, logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil, city: nil, state: nil, invited_manager_email: nil, claim_code: nil, angellist_url: nil, facebook_url: nil, linkedin_url: nil, twitter_url: nil, website_url: nil, longitude: nil, latitude: nil, is_single_use_fund: false, tagline: nil, thumb_file_name: nil, thumb_content_type: nil, thumb_file_size: nil, thumb_updated_at: nil, use_committed_capital: true, owner_id: 3>, #<GroupPortfolio id: 5, name: "New Fund, LLC", established: "2009-01-01", created_at: "2013-09-24 23:20:36", updated_at: "2013-09-24 23:20:36", type: "GroupPortfolio", base_capital_invested: 2000000, total_shares: 1000000, logo_file_name: nil, logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil, city: "Hamlin", state: "WV", invited_manager_email: nil, claim_code: nil, angellist_url: nil, facebook_url: nil, linkedin_url: nil, twitter_url: nil, website_url: nil, longitude: -82.1029, latitude: 38.2787, is_single_use_fund: false, tagline: nil, thumb_file_name: nil, thumb_content_type: nil, thumb_file_size: nil, thumb_updated_at: nil, use_committed_capital: false, owner_id: nil>, #<GroupPortfolio id: 6, name: "SB, LLC", established: "2009-01-01", created_at: "2013-09-24 23:20:36", updated_at: "2013-09-24 23:20:36", type: "GroupPortfolio", base_capital_invested: 2000000, total_shares: 2000000, logo_file_name: nil, logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil, city: "Bloomington", state: "IN", invited_manager_email: nil, claim_code: nil, angellist_url: nil, facebook_url: nil, linkedin_url: nil, twitter_url: nil, website_url: nil, longitude: -86.5264, latitude: 39.1653, is_single_use_fund: false, tagline: nil, thumb_file_name: nil, thumb_content_type: nil, thumb_file_size: nil, thumb_updated_at: nil, use_committed_capital: true, owner_id: nil>] 

1.9.3-p362 :125 > User.find(3).personal_portfolios.first.portfolios_as_viewer.count
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  PersonalPortfolio Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `portfolios`.* FROM `portfolios` INNER JOIN `stakes` ON `portfolios`.`id` = `stakes`.`possession_id` WHERE `stakes`.`type` IN ('UserStakeInPortfolio') AND `portfolios`.`type` IN ('PersonalPortfolio') AND `stakes`.`owner_id` = 3 AND (`portfolios`.`type` = 'PersonalPortfolio') LIMIT 1
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `portfolios` INNER JOIN `permissions` ON `portfolios`.`id` = `permissions`.`entity_id` WHERE `permissions`.`type` IN ('PortfolioPermission') AND `permissions`.`owner_id` = 3 AND (can_view_info = true || can_edit_cap_table = true || can_view_key_metric = true || can_view_all_metrics = true || can_view_cap_table = true || can_edit_managers = true || can_edit_info = true || can_edit_metrics = true)
 => 3 

1.9.3-p362 :126 > User.find(3).personal_portfolios
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  PersonalPortfolio Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `portfolios`.* FROM `portfolios` INNER JOIN `stakes` ON `portfolios`.`id` = `stakes`.`possession_id` WHERE `stakes`.`type` IN ('UserStakeInPortfolio') AND `portfolios`.`type` IN ('PersonalPortfolio') AND `stakes`.`owner_id` = 3 AND (`portfolios`.`type` = 'PersonalPortfolio')
 => [#<PersonalPortfolio id: 3, name: "Manager Man's portfolio", established: "2013-09-24", created_at: "2013-09-24 23:20:34", updated_at: "2013-09-24 23:20:34", type: "PersonalPortfolio", base_capital_invested: nil, total_shares: nil, logo_file_name: nil, logo_content_type: nil, logo_file_size: nil, logo_updated_at: nil, city: nil, state: nil, invited_manager_email: nil, claim_code: nil, angellist_url: nil, facebook_url: nil, linkedin_url: nil, twitter_url: nil, website_url: nil, longitude: nil, latitude: nil, is_single_use_fund: false, tagline: nil, thumb_file_name: nil, thumb_content_type: nil, thumb_file_size: nil, thumb_updated_at: nil, use_committed_capital: true, owner_id: 3>] 

1.9.3-p362 :127 > User.find(3).personal_portfolios.count
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `portfolios` INNER JOIN `stakes` ON `portfolios`.`id` = `stakes`.`possession_id` WHERE `stakes`.`type` IN ('UserStakeInPortfolio') AND `portfolios`.`type` IN ('PersonalPortfolio') AND `stakes`.`owner_id` = 3 AND (`portfolios`.`type` = 'PersonalPortfolio')
 => 1
```

**Another Variation (for illustration/simplicity**

If I change the definition in `personal_portfolio.rb` to:

```
has_many :portfolio_permissions_as_viewer, :class_name => 'PortfolioPermission', :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => { :can_view_info => true }
```

`User.find(3).viewable_portfolios == User.find(3).personal_portfolios.first.portfolios_as_viewer` still returns false.  But `User.find(3).viewable_portfolios`

```
SELECT `portfolios`.*
FROM   `portfolios`
       INNER JOIN `permissions`
               ON `portfolios`.`id` = `permissions`.`entity_id`
       INNER JOIN `portfolios` `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`
               ON `permissions`.`owner_id` =
                  `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`.`id`
       INNER JOIN `stakes`
               ON `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`.`id` =
                  `stakes`.`possession_id`
WHERE  `permissions`.`type` IN ( 'PortfolioPermission' )
       AND `portfolios`.`type` IN ( 'PersonalPortfolio' )
       AND `stakes`.`type` IN ( 'UserStakeInPortfolio' )
       AND `stakes`.`owner_id` = 3
       AND ( `permissions`.`can_view_info` = 1 )
       AND ( `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join`.`type` =
             'PersonalPortfolio' )
```

I think the issue is that it is requiring both `portfolios` and `personal_portfolios_viewable_portfolios_join` to be a `PersonalPortfolio` when in fact `portfolios` should be of any type.  This leads me to believe it is how I have the relationships set up, but not 100% sure.

**Need more?**
Let me know if you need more information/code. I tried not to be too superfluous but might have not given enough to be helpful.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Added above: The Question How can I get `User.find(3).viewable_portfolios` return the same as `User.find(3).personal_portfolios.first.portfolios_as_viewer`?

Comment: What data structure is returned by `User.find(3).personal_portfolios`? An array of 3 `PersonalPortfolio` objects?

Comment: I added some helpful outputs above.  Let me know if you need more.

Comment: I suspect this may be a bug having to do with your `AND` clause with a string passed in. Try it with `has_many :portfolio_permissions_as_viewer, :class_name => 'PortfolioPermission', :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => { :can_edit_managers => true }` just to see if it gives consistent results.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, but assuming you mean convert `has_many :portfolio_permissions_as_manager, :class_name => 'PortfolioPermission', :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => { :can_edit_managers => true }` to `has_many :portfolio_permissions_as_manager2, :class_name => 'PortfolioPermission', :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => 'can_edit_managers = true'` they return the same thing.

Comment: No, I meant exactly what I typed, just try a version of the `has_many :portfolio_permissions_as_viwer` with a hash for the `:conditions` rather than a string.  Then see if you get consistent results or if you still have a mismatch in your queries.

Comment: When redefining it as `has_many :portfolio_permissions_as_viewer, :class_name => 'PortfolioPermission', :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => { :can_edit_managers => true }` it returns what's expected (which is the same as `User.find(3).personal_portfolio.portfolio_permissions_as_manager`).  If you think it's the string `can_view_info = true || can_edit_cap_table = true ||...`, how would you write it as not a string with the ORs?

Comment: Not sure, but hopefully you've at least found the problem.  It could be a bug, but try it as a hash, e.g. `has_many :portfolio_permissions_as_viewer, :class_name => 'PortfolioPermission', :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => { :can_edit_managers => true, :can_edit_cap_table => true, <etc> }`

Comment: Problem though is it needs to be an OR between each attribute, and using `:key => value` pairs produces an AND: `SELECT `permissions`.* FROM `permissions` WHERE `permissions`.`type` IN ('PortfolioPermission') AND `permissions`.`owner_id` = 3 AND `permissions`.`can_view_info` = 1 AND `permissions`.`can_edit_cap_table` = 1 AND `permissions`.`can_view_key_metric` = 1 AND `permissions`.`can_view_all_metrics` = 1 AND `permissions`.`can_view_cap_table` = 1 AND `permissions`.`can_edit_managers` = 1 AND `permissions`.`can_edit_info` = 1 AND `permissions`.`can_edit_metrics` = 1` Thoughts?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38118/discussion-between-ryan-and-tyler)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not be able to do the `OR` comparison as you need.  This might be a bug in Rails but hard to tell.

You could create a method on the model (or even faster, a DB column) that returns `true` or `false` for your long string of comparisons, e.g.

```
def has_permissions_as_viewer
  can_view_info == true || can_edit_cap_table == true || can_view_key_metric == true || can_view_all_metrics == true || can_view_cap_table == true || can_edit_managers == true || can_edit_info == true || can_edit_metrics == true
end
```

and then simply use that method instead of the long conditional

```
has_many :company_permissions_as_viewer, :class_name => 'CompanyPermission', :foreign_key => :owner_id, :conditions => :has_permission_as_viewer
```

It would probably be fastest / most efficient to have a filter on the model that just updates a `has_permission_as_viewer` column whenever any of the other columns are changed (`can_view_info`, `can_edit_cap_table`, etc).  This would also have the added benefits of simpler DB operations and (in my opinion) would be a bit easier to read and understand what's going on.

Let me know if that makes sense!

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, and defining a method is fine except it would be slower if I needed to use that in other models.  That said, I added a "simplified example" to the end of the question to (hopefully) better illustrate the problem.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why don't you think it's the issue?  Based on your comments above, it looked to me like it was definitely the issue.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but doesn't it all work as expected when you use a hash instead of the string-based `OR` clauses?  To test this further, you could try the hash approach with multiple conditions and compare that to the string approach with `AND` clauses to see if they're the same.

Comment: No, it doesn't work.  What I'm looking for is to have `User.find(3).viewable_portfolios == User.find(3).personal_portfolios.first.portfolios_as_viewer` be true.  But it isn't, hash or not.